# what is wrong with printing an int or char array at specified location

Tags: c++, stack, push

I have got a namespace in a header file ,implementing a basic stack.
Now on the push function ,it should push a char on to the stack and
with the pop function it would remove a character from the stack *AND*
here is my problem, print the popped element to the console, but
it actually never does so.
My question is why this happens and what sort of thing I may be missing ?

```
int main()
{
    myStack::push(12);
    myStack::push(344);


    myStack::pop();

    return 0;


}
```

and the header file :

```
void push(int c)
{
    if(top == max_size) throw Overflow();
    v[top] = c;
    top++;
    
}

void pop()
{
    
    printf("%d\n",v[top]);
    top--;
}
```

myStack definition :

```
namespace myStack {

const int max_size = 200;
int top = 0;
int v[max_size];


class Overflow {
    public:
        bool isOverflow = true;
        
};

void push(int c)
{
    if(top == max_size) throw Overflow();
    v[top] = c;
    top++;
    
}

void pop()
{
    
    printf("%d\n",v[top]);
    top--;
}
}
```

Comment: It happens because your code has bugs. Nobody can be more specific than that, given the information you provided.

Comment: Please show a [mre]

Comment: The edit is an improvement, but it's not sufficient. Please show the definition of `myStack`.

Comment: What is the purpose of the header file? It defines a few free functions that you never use. The definitions also look _very_ similar to the free funcions defined in the `myStack` namespace.

Comment: `myStack` should be a class, not a namespace.

Comment: In `pop()`, you probably need to do `top--` _before_ you do the `printf()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that a call to `push` assigns to `v[top]` before incrementing `top`, so in your `pop` function, the value of `top` is an unassigned integer.

You just need to decrement `top` before printing the value of `v[top]`.

```
void pop()
{  
    top--;
    printf("%d\n",v[top]);
}
```

Comment: thank you cigien ,this was what I was looking for. I have recently started to code by the book ,with some examples like this Stack namespace and header files, so sorry if it looks like badly managed code.

Comment: and thanks again ,now it works ,as it should.

Comment: @DenisMuhic Glad it's working. Note that you can accept an answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: @DenisMuhic There should be a checkmark next to the answer that you can click.